# Access .NET Web Service on AWS EC2

Tags: web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created an ASP.NET Web Service and deployed to an AWS EC2 Windows Server. I have opened the associated Port for inbound connections.

But when I try to access the service from another machine, via the browser, the connection just times out.

Does the service need to be consumed by an app/website and have the Server credentials passed in as a parameter? I thought I would be able to access the service publicly from a browser using the Amazon address + service name.

Comment: I am also trying the same to deploy .net core 2.0 web api on aws ec2. but I am getting error (which says)
"An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (WebApplication1.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '2.1.1'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.dll'
  This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files" have you faced any such error while deploying your web service.

Comment: Above error is coming on AWS ec2 Linux version. I know it's an simple dll issue but it should coming by default with the run-time while installing .net runtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common causes of this are the following.

1. Access is blocked by the security group and/or software firewall. Security groups are an EC2 thing and block connects from reaching your instance. Some operating systems have a firewall enabled by default like in your case, windows firewall.
2. Bound to listening on the wrong IP address. The EC2 network is all NAT'd which means the public ip is not actually assigned directly to the interface. The easiest way to fix this is to bind to all IP addresses. If you are using VPC you have some more options with multiple network interfaces.

Comment: Thanks for the response, in the end it was due to an error in my Web Config file, which once resolved worked perfectly

Comment: Let me know If you have any thoughts on below link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46232360/webapi-net-core-2-0-on-aws-ec2-linux-deploying-issue