# WebApi (.Net core 2.0) on aws ec2 (linux) deploying issue

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core

I've built an webapi using .net core 2.0v on my windows system and trying to deploy it on the AWS linux ec2 (Centos v.). To deploy it on the linux machine i've used nginx server as tomcat doesn't support hosting of .net core 2.0 till date (which I read on blogs). Error I am getting which is below

`"An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (WebApplication1.deps.json) was not found: package: 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore', version: '2.1.1' path: 'lib/netstandard1.6/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore‌​.dll' This assembly was expected to be in the local runtime store as the application was published using the following target manifest files"`

I know it's a simple dll issue by reading but what I've tried so far and observed is following

In step 1 when I tried to install .net core 2.0 sdk as per [MSN blog](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#linuxcentos) it isn't allowing me to do so and giving error for few dependencies that it's break (so might be the root cause is that.)

In Step 2 I've checked the opt/dotnet/ dir, In this I am only finding 1.0.0-preview2-1-003177 folder. I am expecting dot net core 2.0 folder should also be there. as i've installed it with a shell script given by [MSN](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/linux). (might be full installation of packages is not yet happened)

In Step 3 I've tried to create a new WebApi Project from Aws terminal by the help of `dotnet new -t` command. but it's giving option for creating only web project. so I created one and in outcome I got a MVC Web Application rather then a WebApi also which was based on dot net 1.0 structure.

> The same if I try on windows VisualStudio command prompt then it's giving me the option of creating WebApi project on terminal.

In Step 4 I've copied my project itself there on ec2 and tried to build it with the help of dotnet command but it's denying for any projects are available on the dir. (might be it's not recognizing the 2.0 application.)

In Step 5 I've tried to publish it with Self contained deployment feature of .net core, and I am finding this option might be helpful in such a scenario but again I am getting below error. In previous version of dot net we tend to solve these errors by writing specific version in web.config files but in .net 2.0 I don't know how to solve specially in self contained deployment.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.Extensions, Version=4.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
```

After doing all these should I treat like .net core 2 or 1 doesn't support webapi on linux environment till date or is there some workaround to do so. I've googled a bit but [everyone is suggesting to depoly web application](https://gooroo.io/GoorooThink/Article/17422/Deploy-ASPNET-Core-Application-On-EC2-Amazon-Linux-Instance/29415#.WbtkUbIjEkJ) (1.0v & MVC application). Or Is there anything I am missing to do on AWS ec2 Linux side.

> Note: Above WebApi I've published on IIS and it's working fine. same dll I've copied into linux and tried with.

In Conclusion I am just trying to deploy an WebService(.Net core 2.0) on AWS ec2 (linux, centos env.) so if anyone of you have done the same let me know above is the my analysis(Which may be wrong)and as per my understanding which is not that much on both of the platform(AWS, .Net core 2).

> After trying Step 5, I am foreseeing that there might be some possibility.